# knockout mapping + add to observable array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, ko.observablearray

Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ92e/3/).

I'm adding to an observable array which is mapped by `ko.mapping.fromJS()`.

In my view I'm building a URL by using a property on the array `attr: { href: '/Users/Summary?userId=' + ID() }`.

If I want to add an item to the array I'm using `self.Users.push()`.

If I do that I get an error of `ID is not a function`.

So my question is whats the correct way of adding an item to the array, or am I not building the `href` attr properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to push a plain object (without observables). You need first construct it, or map it to obsevables.

```
self.Users.push(new User(data));
```

or

```
self.Users.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping));
```

Another alternative would be to just remove the `()` from the expression. But then the observable `ID`-properties will behave strangly.

Comment: Puurfect! I didn't want to remove the () nor did I want to define User for the line self.Users.push(new User(data)). So I changed it to your section option and it worked fine. Thanks!